# What's the advantages in these 2 types of declaration?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question on the styles of declaration of arrays

```
//I get that you may just want to initliaze array with 0s for some reason
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];

//I get that you already know what values you want in this array
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};
```

What's the advantage in declaring in these 2 notations:

```
//Woulnd't I just use the 1st notation for this
int[] myIntArray;
myIntArray=new int[3];
```

---

```
//Wouldn't I just use the 2nd notation for this
 int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

The 4th notation is almost as same as the 2nd notation except the fact that there are 2 references,`myIntArray` and an `anonymous` array, to the object `{1,2,3}` where the 2nd reference,`anonymous` is lost instantly

Comment: The fact that a way do to things exists doesn't imply it's useful.

Comment: 3) may be useful if (for whatever reason) you want to "initialize" the array as `null` and give it a proper (empty) array later; 4) AFAIK is old syntax before (2) was possible but still valid.

Comment: @tobias_k number 3 does **not** set `myIntArray` to null (at least if its a local variable), it leaves it uninitialized instead. Only fields get default values when they are not explicitly initialized.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I learnt that uninitialized referenced variables are `NULL` by default though?

Comment: @HelloWorld: that only applies to fields. Local variables that aren't initialized are simply uninitialized: you won't be allowed to read from them until the compiler is convinced that they have definitely been assigned a value.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll have to read up what fields mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};` and `int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};` is that the first syntax **only** works when initializing a variable.

So if you have code like this:

```
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};
// some code
if (someCondition) {
  myIntArray= new int[] {4, 5, 6};
}
```

You can **not** replace the second one with just `{4, 5, 6}`, because that syntax is reserved for initializing only.

But `new int[] {4, 5, 6}` is a general expression that works basically anywhere.

It's mostly used where you want to construct an array and *not* assign it to a variable, such as directly passing it to a method call:

```
someFunctionTakingAnIntArray(new int[] {3, 4, 5});
```

Comment: Does this mean the 4th notation is only useful in very contrived situations(the array has to be small for me to manually initialize)? Since I can probably use some method to modify the array?

Comment: @HelloWorld: it's useful in any situation where you want to construct a value but *not* assign it to a variable, for example when directly calling a function: `someFunctionTakingIntArray(new int[] {3, 4, 5})`. Here you can't use the shortcut.